# EWS managed api - Marking an email as processed in some way for user

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Im writing a tool that goes through users emails and processes them in some way. Once processed, I would like to modify the email in some way to display the user viewing it in outlook that it was processed, so that it's easy for them to see which have and haven't been. A few ways I've thought of doing it:

- create custom category and set category on processed emails. This is an ideal solution but requires the user to give me access to their calendar to play with their categories -  not feasible in my situation
- modify the email in some way (eg subject) -  would rather leave emails in tact as users may still use them e.g. to respond to
- flag them - not reliable as they may already be flagged and don't want to override.

Are there any other possible things I can do to an email to display to the used its been processed? I basically have owner access on the emails, but nothing else in their mailbox.

Comment: Why do you have to show them that they've been processed? Most companies put a footer in the body (things like virus scanners etc)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the 3 options that you listed, you can also add a user property to the message (`Mailtem.UserProperties.Add`) and modify the folder's view to include that user property.